# what are the different features available in different site templates?

Tags: 2013, site-template, 2016

I tried looking at [microsoft website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410.aspx#Overview%20of%20SharePoint%20sites) which describes about various site templates available. But its on a high level

Is there a comparison of site templates which describes different features available in different site templates?

Comment: Site template is just a features configuration template for a SharePoint Site. Each template has different features activated, but if you would go to site features page, you would be able to activate/deactivate any of the features. This means any of the site template can be changed into another :)

Comment: oh okay! thanks for the information
do you know any links with list of features available by default in site templates?

Comment: I can't seem to find a list of features for each template, but you can find out more about different templates [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) and the list of all available features [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Activate-features-for-sites-787f3ba1-9df6-480a-ab4c-9f4525490cb9). Hope that helps :)